# .grid method will not work Python 3 tkinter. Text boxes are in the same place no matter what I type in the row or column

Tags: python, tkinter

No matter what values I type in the in the row or column on the .grid method; the text boxes still end up in the same place??

The problem is in the PageFour class at the bottom of the code. I want to be able to place the text boxes where I need them. I am new to working with classes and tkinter so any help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana",12)

class SeaofBTCapp (tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default="work.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"The System")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand = True) 
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage,PageOne,PageTwo,PageThree,PageFour):

            frame = F (container,self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
        lable = tk.Label(self,text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Visit Page 1", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self,text="Visit Page 2", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = ttk.Button(self,text="Graph Page", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = ttk.Button(self,text="Tab", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageFour))
        button4.pack()
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
        lable = tk.Label(self,text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Back To Home", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self,text="Page Two", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()  

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
        lable = tk.Label(self,text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Back To Home", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self,text="Page One", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()

class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
        lable = tk.Label(self,text="Graph Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        lable.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Back To Home", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize =(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)


class PageFour(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
        tabcontrol= ttk.Notebook(self)
        tabcontrol.pack(expand=1,fill='both')

        tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
        tabcontrol.add(tab1,text='Tab 1')
        txtbox1 = ttk.Entry(tab1, width=12, textvariable = tk.StringVar())
        txtbox1.grid(column=0,row=3)

        txtbox2 = ttk.Entry(tab1, width=12, textvariable = tk.StringVar())
        txtbox2.grid(column=0,row=10)


        tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
        tabcontrol.add(tab2,text='Tab 2')

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Back To Home", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop ()
```

Comment: empty row/column has no size so if you put in row 1 and you have empty rows 0 then you will see no difference. You can use `rowconfig(0, minsize=10)` to change size of row 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be placed one beneath each other no matter what You enter for `row`. Why? If there are no widgets in rows between, `tkinter` will ignore non-existing rows and it will place rows which have something in them one beneath other.

How to solve this? I see two approaches:

1. Use `place` instead of `grid` (not recommended for beginners, difficult to place widgets)
2. Use `Label` widgets and place them in rows between those 2 You really need (which is not very good programming practice)

Comment: txtbox1 = ttk.Entry(tab1, width=12, textvariable = tk.StringVar())
txtbox1.place(x=20,y=50) The Place method works great

Comment: @ZacAttack: `place` works fine in this exact scenario, but as soon as you run on a different resolution or on a different system or resize the window, it starts to become difficult to get it to look right under every condition. That is why `place` is rarely recommended as the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

> No matter what values I type in the in the row or column on the .grid method; the text boxes still end up in the same place??

No. They won't. e.g. -

```
txtbox1.grid(column=0, row=0); txtbox2.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

vs. `txtbox1.grid(column=1, row=1); txtbox2.grid(column=0, row=0)`

Not the same place, although it will *look* identitcal.

Now, considering your using `row=3` and `row=10` I'm assuming you expect there to be some "gap" between the widgets and rows. There won't be. The widgets will appear to be one row after the other in the grid system.